# Simple API Manager HA Setup

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, high-availability, api-manager

I am trying to deploy API Manager in a simple HA configuration.  I'd like the entire API Manager setup on server A, and just the API Gateway on server B.

I'm trying to follow the instructions on the following link:  http://docs.wso2.org/display/Cluster/Clustering+API+Manager

My question is, how do I remove the store and publisher from server B, as instructed by this sentance:  "To set up each API Manager component in separate servers, simply remove the unwanted Jaggery apps from the deployment directory. For example, to set up only API Gateway in a severer, remove the store and publisher Jaggery apps.".

I have SVN Deployment Synchronization set up as per the following link with server A the master:  http://docs.wso2.org/display/Cluster/Configuring+Deployment+Synchronizer

If I remove the store and publisher from jaggeryapps on server B, won't the deployment sychronizer just put them back the next time I restart server B?

Comment: Please tag more carefully. This is NOT [tag:cluster-analysis] (a data mining technique, known as "clustering")

Answer (score 0):

Those are webapps, you can simply delete the jaggery webapps from AM_HOME\repository\deployment\server\jaggeryapps.

Deployment synchornizer won't put back the webapps again. You have to again deploy both jaggery apps in the same folder

Comment: Hi Ratha.  Does the deployment synchronizer only run once at startup?  That's the behavior I'm seeing.  When I publish APIs, they don't show up in synapse-config on the 2nd machine until after I restart APIM on that machine.  Also, publisher and store get restored on startup of APIM after I've deleted them off that machine.  Any way to prevent that?

Comment: "svn delete" of publisher and store seems to work.  And once I clustered the two APIM instances, the worker does an svn update every time there is a change to the master.